# Windows Batch For Loop Error

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch file that will patch a series of database instances.. 
The issue is that I keep getting the error

> "i was unexpected at this time."

I'm running this from CMD directly if that makes any difference to solving the issue.

```
for /l %i in (1, 1, 51) do
( 
    (echo @?/sqlpatch/18881811/postinstall.sql
    ) | sqlplus -s CONNECT / AS SYSDBA@orc%i
)
```

Comment: Read the help of `for` when typing `for /?` into a command prompt window -- it clearly mentions that you need to double the `%` signs if `for` is used in batch files...

Comment: You only need to use `%%`, if you put the statement in a batch file, but you have use a single `%`, if you are running the commands directly from the command line.

Comment: Please do not edit your question such that it invalidates existing answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the code block on the command line, move the opening bracket "(" to the end of the first line. Otherwise, the first line produces a syntax error. That is why you are calling `sqlplus -s CONNECT / AS SYSDBA@orc%i` once, producing the "i was unexpected at this time" message", instead of calling this:

```
sqlplus -s CONNECT / AS SYSDBA@orc1
...
sqlplus -s CONNECT / AS SYSDBA@orc51
```

So the correct loop looks like this:

```
for /l %i in (1, 1, 51) do ( 
    (echo @?/sqlpatch/18881811/postinstall.sql
    ) | sqlplus -s CONNECT / AS SYSDBA@orc%i
)
```

---

*Please remember to change `%i` to `%%i`, if you put the code into a batch file.*
*This is because in batch files, a single percent sign is used to refer to command line arguments, provided by the caller of the batch file.*